# Facebook Connect - Install GIT,  #import "Facebook.h"  "file not found"

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, fbconnect

I am **trying** to follow the tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/
and am having loads of errors and Questions. What is the GIT i installed it like it said in the tutorial but i was of no use. Also i have the line of code

```
#import "Facebook.h"
```

which gives me the error "file not found"

please help i have been working on Facebook for months

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think here your SDK miss the FBBundle so this is happen may be....
so use latest SDK and implement with its API key if you want demo then here is link...

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

but this link use another SDK...
hope this help you....
:)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Facebook.h file doesn't exist in the SDK anymore. I downloaded the 3.1 SDK, did a search for Facebook.h and there was nothing. Further, looking in the Headers folder of the SDK, I do not see anything in there that did not start with FB. I wish there was a textbook for this stuff. The FB tutorials online do not seem to be much help.